# Pandas:Unique values of a column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in a dataframe:fueltype and number of doors.Fueltype has 3 categories:Petrol,Diesel and CNG.How do I find the unique values of number of doors in petrol fueltype?

Comment: df[df.fueltype == "petrol"].drop_duplicates()

Answer (score 0):

Say that your dataframe looks like this:

```
   fueltype   number of doors
0     Petrol                2
1     Petrol                4
2     Petrol                4
3     Petrol                4
4     Diesel                2
5     Diesel                2
6     Diesel                4
7     Diesel                4
8     Diesel                4
9     Diesel                4
10       CNG                2
11       CNG                2
12       CNG                4
13       CNG                2
14       CNG                4
```

then this:

```
group = df.groupby('fueltype')
df2 = group.apply(lambda x: x['number of doors'].unique())
```

gives you the unique value for each category of fuels

```
fueltype 
CNG       [2, 4]
Diesel    [2, 4]
Petrol    [2, 4]
dtype: object
```

**EDIT**

If you want to all all unique values for each fueltype:

```
df2.explode()
```

will return

```
fueltype 
CNG       2
CNG       4
Diesel    2
Diesel    4
Petrol    2
Petrol    4
dtype: object
```

Comment: The dataset I am using has 264000 rows.So all the unique values in each category are not fully displayed in this method.It looks like[2,3,4,.......].Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I am still facing the same problem because of its size.Is there a way so i could see the unique values for petrol alone?

Comment: I am still facing the same problem because of its size.It shows CNG 2 ........Petrol 4 vertically